# How to use otf type font file in Android Compose？

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm learning to use Android Jetpack Compose.
Now I have a **Regular.otf** font file in **assets/font**. I want to use it in Text.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Font asset not found /commonui/src/main/assets/font/Regular.otf
    at android.graphics.Typeface.createFromFile(Typeface.java:998)
    at android.graphics.Typeface.createFromFile(Typeface.java:1012)
```

I tried some methods but none of them solved.

```
    val fontFamily = FontFamily(
        typeface = Typeface.createFromFile("commonui/src/main/assets/font/Regular.otf")
    )
    Text(
        text = "Font",
        style = TextStyle(fontFamily = fontFamily)
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace line with this

typeface =  Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"font/Regular.otf")

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 4):

You should put the font resource in the `res/font/` folder and name it in lowercase, for example `regular.otf`. It is also probably a good idea to give it a real font name rather than a font style name. Read more about adding font resources in [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/font-resource).

You can then use `ResourcesCompat` inside composable, providing the context from `LocalContext`.

To avoid unnecessary calculations, you should at least put it inside `remember`, but ideally move it to your theme. Check out more about [Theming in Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/themes)

```
val context = LocalContext.current
val fontFamily = remember {
    FontFamily(
        typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.regular)!!
    )
}
Text(
    "Hello",
    style = TextStyle(fontFamily = fontFamily),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to rename your font to lower cases as per google recommendations.

Further you can set font using:

```
  myTextView.typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(this, R.font.regular)
```

For more details refer to :
https://johncodeos.com/how-to-add-custom-fonts-in-your-android-app-using-kotlin/

Comment: The post is clearly referencing using Jetpack Compose, not the traditional XML views. This link is not helpful for the original question