# Jetpack compose get FontFamily from resources

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-theme

In `res/font` I have defined `font-family` like this:

```
<font-family xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <font app:fontStyle="normal" app:fontWeight="400" app:font="xyz_1"/>
    <font app:fontStyle="normal" app:fontWeight="500" app:font="xyz_2"/>
</font-family>
```

How I can load this in Jetpack Compose and use it as `FontFamily` object?

Comment: Try this solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/69044509/10954249

Comment: It is strange but when I try to do it like this and set font weight to medium it doesn't changes anything

Comment: can you please add the code to your question it's better to understand?

Comment: If you still want to keep the XML, I might have a workaround gor this while it is unsupported, but it includes some legacy APIs. Like `android.graphics.*` instead of their Compose Equivalents. This works for stuff like `Text`, but might need tinkering for input fields.

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately there isn't yet a straightforward solution to load Font-Familys directly in compose from xml.

I'd consider the following options:

1. Define the material design text styles (body1, body2, etc..) in xml for the theme and use [MDC-theme adapter](https://material-components.github.io/material-components-android-compose-theme-adapter/) to migrate them to `MaterialTheme.typography`
2. The above might not work for special font familys, for example a logo or other use-cases. In that case I'd go with recreating the FontFamily for compose:

```
private val appFontFamily = FontFamily(
   fonts = listOf(
       Font(
           resId = R.font.roboto_black, 
           weight = FontWeight.W900, 
           style = FontStyle.Normal
       ),
       Font(
           resId = R.font.roboto_black_italic, 
           weight = FontWeight.W900, 
           style = FontStyle.Italic
       ),
       Font(
           resId = R.font.roboto_bold, 
           weight = FontWeight.W700, 
           style = FontStyle.Normal
       ),
       ...
   )
)
```

Here is a good read about this: https://alexzh.com/jetpack-compose-theme-and-typography/. Also one could get inspired and contribute to the Mdc-theme adapter to cover these special use-cases that are outside of the theme as well. I suppose the logic of reading in text styles to compose is already there, one just needs to provide an API to read in custom ones, other than the ones specified in the Material Theme.

Comment: Thanks for Your answer. But the problem is that In my app I have a core library with some views that are made in compose. This library is used in other apps and different font has to be used for each app. To solve this in a library, I can add font `xyz` and then in apps that use this library add a font that I want with name `xyz`, and font will be overridden. But I think this is not the best way of doing this.

Answer (score 7):

```
val FontName = FontFamily(
    Font(R.font.font_reg, FontWeight.Normal),
    Font(R.font.font_light,FontWeight.Light),
    Font(R.font.font_sbold, FontWeight.SemiBold),
    Font(R.font.font_xbold, FontWeight.ExtraBold)
)
```

In any Kotlin file (outside class)

Then use in any composable:

```
@Composable
    fun FontStyledText(text: String) {
        Text(
            text = text,
            fontFamily = FontName,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.SemiBold
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

for any one who wants to change the app's font do the following

1. Create font directory in res (res/font)
2. copy your .ttf fonts in res/font
3. find the Type.kt file ( in ui/theme directory )
4. create a variable for font in Type.kt

   ```
   val MyCustomFont = FontFamily(
       Font(R.font.regular),
       Font(R.font.bold,FontWeight.Bold)
   )
   ```
5. there is Typography val in Type.kt file, you can change the entire app's font family by putting defaultFontFamily = MyCustomFont in this val

   ```
   val Typography = Typography(
       defaultFontFamily = MyCustomFont,
       body1 = TextStyle(
           fontFamily = MyCustomFont2,
           fontWeight = FontWeight.Normal,
           fontSize = 16.sp
    ),
   ```
6. you can also set font family to specific typography like body1, h1, h2, ...

Edit: to change font for Material 3 add the following in Type.kt

```
    bodyLarge = TextStyle(
    fontFamily = MyCustomFont,
    fontWeight = FontWeight.Normal,
    fontSize = 16.sp,
    lineHeight = 24.sp,
    letterSpacing = 0.5.sp
),
displayLarge= TextStyle(fontFamily = MyCustomFont),
displayMedium= TextStyle(fontFamily = MyCustomFont),
displaySmall= TextStyle(fontFamily = MyCustomFont),
headlineLarge= TextStyle(fontFamily = MyCustomFont),
headlineMedium= TextStyle(fontFamily = MyCustomFont),
headlineSmall= TextStyle(fontFamily = MyCustomFont),
titleLarge= TextStyle(fontFamily = MyCustomFont),
titleMedium= TextStyle(fontFamily = MyCustomFont),
titleSmall= TextStyle(fontFamily = MyCustomFont),
bodyMedium= TextStyle(fontFamily = MyCustomFont),
bodySmall= TextStyle(fontFamily = MyCustomFont),
labelLarge= TextStyle(fontFamily = MyCustomFont),
labelMedium= TextStyle(fontFamily = MyCustomFont),
labelSmall= TextStyle(fontFamily = MyCustomFont),
```

Comment: Worked well. Kindly add  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76379435/6039129) copy method to make this solution complete. Because the default properties are lost after this solution

Answer (score 3):

If you need to use your font directly in your Compose Text, you can call **your_font_file_name.otf** file name without " ***.otf*** " in Compose Text.

Quick answer:

```
fontFamily = FontFamily(Font(R.font.your_font_file_name))
```

Example:

```
Text(
  text = "your_text" // OR stringResource(id = R.string.your_string_id),
  fontSize = 16.sp,
  fontFamily = FontFamily(Font(R.font.your_font_file_name))
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the font-family XML file from `res/font` directory. You have to introduce each font file using Kotlin, then you can use it. All other solutions are given in Material2. So, here is the M3 solution for setting default font-family.

---

For Material3 (Material Design 3):

> Note: Unlike the M2 Typography class, the M3 Typography class doesn’t
> currently include a `defaultFontFamily` parameter. You’ll need to use
> the `fontFamily` parameter in each of the individual TextStyles instead.
> ([Source](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/designsystems/material3#typography))

So, here is an example of setting the default font-family in M3:

```kotlin
// Type.kt

import androidx.compose.material3.Typography
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.Font
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontFamily
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontStyle
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontWeight
import com.example.exampleapp.R

// Declare the font families
object AppFont {
    val TitilliumWeb = FontFamily(
        Font(R.font.titillium_web_regular),
        Font(R.font.titillium_web_italic, style = FontStyle.Italic),
        Font(R.font.titillium_web_medium, FontWeight.Medium),
        Font(R.font.titillium_web_medium_italic, FontWeight.Medium, style = FontStyle.Italic),
        Font(R.font.titillium_web_bold, FontWeight.Bold),
        Font(R.font.titillium_web_bold_italic, FontWeight.Bold, style = FontStyle.Italic)
    )
}

private val defaultTypography = Typography()
val Typography = Typography(
    displayLarge = defaultTypography.displayLarge.copy(fontFamily = AppFont.TitilliumWeb),
    displayMedium = defaultTypography.displayMedium.copy(fontFamily = AppFont.TitilliumWeb),
    displaySmall = defaultTypography.displaySmall.copy(fontFamily = AppFont.TitilliumWeb),

    headlineLarge = defaultTypography.headlineLarge.copy(fontFamily = AppFont.TitilliumWeb),
    headlineMedium = defaultTypography.headlineMedium.copy(fontFamily = AppFont.TitilliumWeb),
    headlineSmall = defaultTypography.headlineSmall.copy(fontFamily = AppFont.TitilliumWeb),

    titleLarge = defaultTypography.titleLarge.copy(fontFamily = AppFont.TitilliumWeb),
    titleMedium = defaultTypography.titleMedium.copy(fontFamily = AppFont.TitilliumWeb),
    titleSmall = defaultTypography.titleSmall.copy(fontFamily = AppFont.TitilliumWeb),

    bodyLarge = defaultTypography.bodyLarge.copy(fontFamily = AppFont.TitilliumWeb),
    bodyMedium = defaultTypography.bodyMedium.copy(fontFamily = AppFont.TitilliumWeb),
    bodySmall = defaultTypography.bodySmall.copy(fontFamily = AppFont.TitilliumWeb),

    labelLarge = defaultTypography.labelLarge.copy(fontFamily = AppFont.TitilliumWeb),
    labelMedium = defaultTypography.labelMedium.copy(fontFamily = AppFont.TitilliumWeb),
    labelSmall = defaultTypography.labelSmall.copy(fontFamily = AppFont.TitilliumWeb)
)
```

```kotlin
// Theme.kt

import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable

@Composable
fun AppTheme(
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    MaterialTheme(
        typography = Typography,
        content = content
    )
}
```

Example for an individual component:

```kotlin
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import com.example.exampleapp.theme.AppFont

@Composable
fun ExampleScreen() {
    Text(
        text = "Hello World!", 
        fontFamily = AppFont.TitilliumWeb
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val QuickSand = FontFamily(
    Font(R.font.quicksand_light, weight = FontWeight.Light),
    Font(R.font.quicksand_regular, weight = FontWeight.Normal),
    Font(R.font.quicksand_medium, weight = FontWeight.Medium),
    Font(R.font.quicksand_semibold, weight = FontWeight.SemiBold),
    Font(R.font.quicksand_bold, weight = FontWeight.Bold)
)

// Set of Material typography styles to start with
val Typography = Typography(
    body1 = TextStyle(
        fontFamily = QuickSand,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.Light,
        fontSize = 16.sp,
    ),
    h1 = TextStyle(
        fontFamily = QuickSand,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.SemiBold,
        fontSize = 24.sp
    ),
    h2 = TextStyle(
        fontFamily = QuickSand,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
        fontSize = 22.sp
    )
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).